# Asynchronous timer callback on Windows

Tags: windows, asynchronous, timer, signals

I am looking for a Windows replacement for the *nix `SIGALRM`. I have seen suggested (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511732/alarm-function-on-linux-and-windows-cant-find-a-equivalent-for-windows-c)) to use `timeSetEvent`, but that doesn't quite do the same. `SIGALRM` calls the callback function *on the same thread* as the rest of my (single threaded) program, where as, as far as I understand, `timeSetEvent` calls it on a *new* thread.

Am I right about this distinction? If so, is there some way to achieve the *nix type behavior on Windows?

Comment: Your assumptions are not correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586926/setitimer-sigalrm-multithread-process-linux-c

Comment: @HansPassant No, that answer says that the signal is handled by one of the *existing* threads. Since this is a single-threaded application, my assumption that the callback is handled on my main thread is correct. `timeSetEvent`, if I understand correctly, creats a whole new thread to handle the callback.