# Is it possible to create "quick time events" in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I have some knowledge about C++, but I stumbled upon an problem. I want the user to enter some text, but when it takes longer than X seconds, the program will go on. I guess, it is not possible, but maybe you know something about it.

It will be in the command line, without GUI.
I am not certain how the programm will look like, but it will be something like a CMD-RPG. I wanted to use Quick Time Events to make it a little bit more exciting.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.  What kind of program?

Comment: Is this going to be command line or GUI?

Comment: You'll need to set up some threading to get this done. A timer thread that will emit a TIMEOUT signal and another thread that will emit a RESPONSE_GIVEN signal. The main running thread will have to dispatch both of these and wait for either of these signals and respond accordingly.

Comment: This is not possible with standard C++ alone. You need some platform specific code (or library which does this). So you need to give more details about restrictions and programming environment than just "C++".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811438/input-with-a-timeout-in-c seems seems exact duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input with a timeout in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811438/input-with-a-timeout-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant comment so I will just leave this here

> [Input with a timeout in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811438/input-with-a-timeout-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment, I will simply leave this as an answer.

One possible way to solve this problem is to have 2 threads:

Input capture thread: since receiving input is a thread-blocking action, you should have a thread that simply polls for user input, placing that input into a thread-safe buffer

Quick-time function on main thread: a function that will be responsible for executing the quick-time event. Something like the following could be done (pseudo code):

```
clear input buffer //the buffer provided by the input capture thread

bool success = false;

while(current time < ending time)
{
    if(input buffer isn't empty)
    {
        get contents of input buffer and send contents to cout
        if (user has finished input correctly)
        {
            success = true;
            break;
        }
        clear buffer
    }
}
return success;
```

For this to work, you would need to turn off `echo` on the command prompt (see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo) for more info)

<s>Although Diogo's reference is excellent (and informative), I believe this answer is more applicable than  since the OP has indicated that this program will be ran on Windows.</s>